# move paid paypal orders from shopping cart to Orders

Tags: payment-gateways, commerce

I have an issue where people paying by paypal aren't completing the shopping workflow by returning back to site and therefore some orders are stuck in shopping cart with status of Shopping cart:Confirm Order.
When I goto Store -> Orders these are in the Shopping cart Tab.

I could edit order and complete transaction manually but is there a rule based or code I could run to occasionally update orders in this status.
or a View I could create which I could set status for these orders?